# adding jquery plugin to Zurb's Foundation Framework

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, zurb-foundation

I am working with Zurbs's Foundation rapid prototyping framework and very good it is to.  I am wondering the proper way to integrate another jquery plugin into it.

foundations is very picky about how you include other plugins.  Part of the frameworks is an app.js file full of functions.  Should I be adding my new functions direct to there?

Whilst I do understand js (reading ok) I am no js expert so a clearly explained answer please.

Thanks

(site working on is vincentstephens.co.uk/vs5.1/portfolio - trying to integrate a time line slider located at vincentstephens.co.uk/vs5.1/portfolio/portfolio.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I'm missing out on something but you don't need to *integrate it to foundation*. If you have another jquery plugin in just include the .js as any script and you're done.

The `foundation.min.js` is a minified file with all foundation plugins as well as jquery - you might want to minify your plugin and add to this file for the purpose of optimizing.

The `app.js` is where you initialize the plugins. This is generally the file you fiddle your own settings and preferred default values, not touching the `foundation.min.js`.

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Much neater to keep the functions that execute the plugins with their settings in another file (app.js) so they are universally accessible.