# After adding Foundation Javascript jQuery cookie no longer works

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, zurb-foundation

> This question is related to the answer of
>   [adding jquery plugin to Zurb's Foundation Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12318925/adding-jquery-plugin-to-zurbs-foundation-framework),
>   but it's missing how to implement it to app.js

I use [zurb-foundation](/questions/tagged/zurb-foundation) to maintain layout. I also use jQuery cookie plugin. After adding Foundation JavaScript as described under HTML Page Markup in [this document](http://foundation.zurb.com/old-docs/f3/index.php), I noticed that the jQuery cookie plugin does not work. I get this error message in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (e,t){return new y.fn.init(e,t,n)} has no method 'cookie' 8:184
(anonymous function) 8:184
o jquery.min.js:2
p.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.B jquery.min.js:2
```

Is there any way to include the jQuery cookie plugin in app.js of Foundation? Or is there any other solution?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution. It is just a matter of javascripts files order linking. In other word, I have to link to Jquery.cookie after linking to foundation.min.js and app.js not before them. so the final order of Javascript linking should be as:

> 'jquery','modernizr.foundation','foundation.min','app','jquery.cookie','jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min'.

Answer (score 1):

I really do not know about "zurb-foundation" but I just want to show you another way of using cookies without $.cookie plugin

If you dont worry about IE7 or less, you can use HTML5's Local Storage.

for more info: [HTML5-Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use $.cookie plugin. I believe that app.js should be deal in some way to allow regarding the plugin, but I don't know how?